# How can I convert the stream into a file using AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Already I am returning a file stream (`StreamingOutput`) from the server. I need to convert the file stream into a file using `AngularJS` or `javascript` or `JQuery` or any other libraries.

What I want is need to show the file in a `<div>` or any other HTML element.

Ex: `Gmail attachments. If we click the attachments we can see it in a popup. I want the same`

Also **if the stream is a zipped file then it should be extracted out and show the actual file** in the view (`<div>`).

Comment: I haven't tried anything. Since I don't have any idea to do this.

Comment: Hey i had this issue previously for downloading file through ajax, just check out my answer, expecting more queries ...

Comment: @Prince is that your requirement....

Comment: No this is not my requirement. May be my question is not clear. Please review my updated question

Comment: @NidhishKrishnan  Instead of this library you can easily download the file using "download" attribute. For eg: <a download="fileName" href="rest/url" >fileName</a>. If needed try this

Comment: @Prince but that would make the browser to perform a full page reload to the original link for download....its not AJAX-Based

Comment: @NidhishKrishnan: Add target="_self" then it will not perform a full page reload to the original link for download.

Comment: @NidhisKrishnan: Can you help me based on my updated question?

Answer (score 0):

Try **[jQuery File Download v1.2.0 plugin](http://johnculviner.com/jquery-file-download-v1-2-0-released-and-on-github/)** for downloading any file through `Ajax`. Its the only plugin which i found working for `Ajax` file download and which is promising and works for all broswers. You can use even use this with `AngularJS`.

Try out this code

```
$scope.downLoadFile = function()
{
    $scope.jsonData = []; // put what-ever you want
    $.fileDownload('/yourRestService/downloadFile', {
        httpMethod : "POST",
        data : {
            param : $scope.jsonData
        }
    }).done(function(e, response)
    {
    }).fail(function(e, response)
    {
      console.log("File Download Failed");
    });
}
```